# Found 4 vulnerabilities on npm install

Tags: reactjs, security, react-native, npm

I am just getting started with react-native. On installing this package

```
npm install --save react-native-validator-form
```

https://github.com/NewOldMax/react-native-validator-form/issues/3

I was prompted to `npm audit` and I was shown 4 vulnerabilities (listed above)

After running the 2 helper commands, I was prompted with another 2 vulnerabilities (see link)

How can I fix the remaining issues?

Updating the respective npm packages didn't work.

Not sure how to proceed?

Comment: Just to make things a bit more interesting, I thought I'd run `npm audit` in another directory. I got 164 vulnerabilities found - Packages audited: 20493 (312 dev, 1044 optional). Severity: 110 low | 35 moderate | 19 high.

Comment: have reduced this to 20 low | 33 moderate | 15 high in project B, other directory. Is this a cause for serious concern??

Comment: Try with "npm audit fix --force"

Comment: In March 2023, the package `react-native-validator-form` has *0 vulnerabilities*,
so apparently, it has since been fixed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a result of the new npm version including the audit command.

It isn't some new issue with the Angular CLI, npm just introduced new functionality in npm to warn users about vulnerabilities in the packages they're installing - so there's no "new" vulnerability in Angular, it's just that now npm is now warning you about vulnerabilities that already existed:

https://blog.npmjs.org/

Most of the issues stem from Karma, so it'd need to be fixed there for the Angular team to pull in a new Karma version karma-runner/karma#2994

Comment: So what is the fix?

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Answer (score 29):

If you have ran `npm audit` and got vulnerabilities, then you can have different scenarios:

### Security vulnerabilities found with suggested updates

- Run the npm audit fix subcommand to automatically install compatible updates to vulnerable dependencies.
- Run the recommended commands individually to install updates to vulnerable dependencies. (Some updates may be semver-breaking changes; for more information, see "SEMVER warnings".)

### Security vulnerabilities found requiring manual review

- If security vulnerabilities are found, but no patches are available, the audit report will provide information about the vulnerability so you can investigate further.

Source: [Reviewing and acting on the security audit report](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/running-a-security-audit#reviewing-and-acting-on-the-security-audit-report)

Answer (score 15):

Even after running `npm audit fix` if it is not fixed, then to proceed I think you should Turn off npm audit. Use below command to turn off npm audit.

when installing a single package.

```
npm install example-package-name --no-audit
```

To turn off npm audit when installing all packages

```
npm set audit false
```

it will set the audit setting to false in your user and global npmrc config files.

for reference visit : [turn-off-npm-audit](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities#turning-off-npm-audit-on-package-installation)

Comment: This is basically...
Silencing the alert?

Comment: Yes it is silencing the alert, but I upvoted anyway, because these alerts inform the wrong people. The intention behind them is not to help by giving us solutions that work. This audit fix solution does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and log was like below:

```
Testing binary
Binary is fine
added 1166 packages from 1172 contributors and audited 39128 packages in 112.505s
found 1 high severity vulnerability
```

I executed the below command and it was fixed.

```
npm audit fix
```

log shows as below:

```
Testing binary
Binary is fine
+ @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.11.4
added 18 packages from 47 contributors, removed 14 packages and updated 52 packages in 64.529s
fixed 1 of 1 vulnerability in 39128 scanned packages
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while installing `react-native navigation`, using:

```
npm install react-navigation
```

For me, `npm audit-fix` didn't worked well. **npm** use to have some limitations. For me, yarn worked:

```
yarn add <package-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the vulnerabilities issues of the package, run `npm audit fix`
it will fix all the vulnerabilities that can be auto-fixed
But it will not fix the high vulnerabilities, in order to fix the high vulnerabilities, you can checkout the package that is causing the vulnerabilities on npmjs.org and try installing the new version of it,
In some cases,you may need to remove it and replace it with other alternative because some packages may be vulnerable to your application

Thank you

Answer (score -7):

I had the same problem while running this command:

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

...and solved it by running the Command Prompt as **Administrator**.

So **Open the Command Prompt as Administrator** and then try again. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: OP never mentioned he was on Windows. Also, how will having higher permissions on the project fix vulnerabilities in the dependencies.

Comment: You should never ever run ```npm install``` with administrative privileges! You should change the folder privileges, not the command. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo/24404451#24404451)

Comment: that is a dangerous practice. Don't do that.