# found 11 high severity vulnerabilities when installing function framework on my cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

so I am trying to use cloud functions, and I want to test to run my function locally. so I try to use [Function Framework](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework).

but it seems I failed to install the package, it is said, found 11 high severity vulnerabilities  like this:

[image]

> added 2 packages from 2 contributors and audited 1039 packages in
>   5.687s found 11 high severity vulnerabilities

[image]

so when I try to run my code locally. I failed with this error:

> Error: Cannot find module
>   '/Users/muchammadagunglaksana/Documents/kumpul_muslim/cloud_functions_serverless_backend/functions/functions-framework'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3) Muchammads-MacBook-Air:functions muchammadagunglaksana$ node
>   functions-framework --target=helloWorld
>   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module
>   '/Users/muchammadagunglaksana/Documents/kumpul_muslim/cloud_functions_serverless_backend/functions/functions-framework'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

even though it seems it has been installed in package.json
[image]

what went wrong in here ?

Comment: most of the time, you can [do nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243901/found-4-vulnerabilities-on-npm-install) until the package fixed by their devs. however, you can try `npm audit fix --force` and see if there is new version with the issue fixed already. i also noticed your `firebase-admin` is not of latest.

Comment: Please don't show screenshots of text.  It's easier to read and search if you simply copy the text into the question itself.

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you for the remainder. I have added the text of the error as well

Comment: There's still plenty of text here that could be moved out of images into the question (like all of them, as it doesn't matter if you're using VS code or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not fail to install the package, it apparently contains some security vulnerabilities, but it still installs normally.

You're getting an error since you're using the `node` command wrong. It cannot find the module, since when you're running `node functions-framework --target=helloWorld`, it is looking for a file called `functions-framework` in your current directory.
You should rather use npm to run the binary. Add a run script in `package.json`.
Something like this

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "functions-framework --target=helloWorld"
}
```

Then use `npm run start`.