# React library vulnerability and risk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, react-redux

Hello I recently installed react-redux and saw on my console after it was downloaded that there were vulnerabilities low and high. What does this mean? Should I uninstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Npm installer include audit system of scanning your project for vulnerabilities. You can try to run this command to automatically fix vulnerabilities, maybe it will update version of react-redux or some dependencies

```
npm audit fix
```

You can try to read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50574347/4459474

Comment: Thank you. In the process of running npm audit fix

Comment: Okay so it fixed all the vulnerabilities except for one and it says that will need manual review. I can I review and fix it manually?

Comment: @ForestProgramming Yes you can, in documentation it is described here https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities#fix-the-vulnerability But honestly I never fixed such vulnerabilities by yourself, because you need deep understanding of module which has vulnerability...

Answer (score 0):

Chances are this warning was caused by other library you have also installed.
Try to execute `npm audit fix` command to let npm attempt to auto fix vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. How can I check to see if there are anymore vulnerabilities once npm audit fix is complete?

Comment: It will show you in console what was fixed and what npm wasn't able to fix and needs to be manually checked.