# Electron Js Venurability

Tags: javascript, npm, electron

From last few days I am facing an issue with Electron JS. That is whenever I install electron it says that some venerability is there. I want to fix it, I have tried several fixes but any of these didn't worked. Like this: -

added 52 packages, changed 86 packages, and audited 1748 packages in 18s

134 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

87 vulnerabilities (86 moderate, 1 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

Please help me.
Sorry for my bad English.
Please don't close this question. I am just a beginner.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Found 4 vulnerabilities on npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243901/found-4-vulnerabilities-on-npm-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for raising query

i think vulnerability message that you are getting need not be from electron it could be from your other manually installed dependencies as well.

> **Why Do we get Vulnerability Error ?**

whenever we install any package using package manager npm audit command get executed automatically this command search the vulnerability in your installed dependencies that could cause data loss, service outages, unauthorized access to sensitive information, or other issues.

to know from where this error coming you need to run npm audit command manually and base on the output of the command you will get to know which installed dependency causing issue.

1. On the command line, navigate to your package directory by typing cd
   path/to/your-package-name and pressing Enter.
2. Ensure your package contains package.json and package-lock.json files.
3. Type npm audit and press Enter.
4. Review the audit report and run recommended commands or investigate further if
   needed.

for more info please visit
https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities