# npm installed deprecated packages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dependencies

i started a react project for training and after downloading nodejs v18, i type npm init -y and everything seems to be ok. Then i installed react and other dependencies as following: [dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7VpU.png) but vscode shell shows this message:"76 vulnerabilities (12 low, 20 moderate, 40 high, 4 critical)"

What's going wrong?

thx in advance

i tried npm audit fix, npm audit fix --force but doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

npm introduced new functionality in npm to warn users about vulnerabilities in the packages they're installing

you can found the detailed description below link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243901/found-4-vulnerabilities-on-npm-install)

Comment: Hi, it's better to link `npm` docs, not a SO answer